# Centering a div with words and a picture

Tags: html, css, containers, center

I am trying to center a div that contains  two divs- one is a paragraph, the other an image. I tried to apply auto 0 margins to the container div, but it didn't center anything. Is there a way to get everything to center while preserving the formatting I have done in the smaller divs? 
My code

```css
.whole {
  height: 800px;
  max-width: 98%;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.about-text {
  width: 40%;
  color: #66096c;
  font-family: Lucida bright;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1.8 em;
  padding-right: 6em;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.about_pic {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div class="about-text">
    <p> <strong> Hi, I'm Kelsie. </strong> 
      <p>
        <p>Hello there.
          <br />My name is Kelsie, and I like to create things. So I decided to do it for a job. I am learning how to do this at Michigan State University, where I study professional writing. This program teaches web design, print design, editing, and writing.
          I am also learning about how to make rhetorical decisions that will have a positive impact on an audience by studying visual design principles, website accessibility and usability laws, and persuasion techniques.</p>
        <p>I live in East Lansing where I am a full-time student. So basically I study all the time. On the rare occasions that I do have some free time, I like to read, shop, and visit my <span> home</span> cats.</p>
        <p>Want to create something together? Me too. Send me a message using the contact form, and let's get together.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="about_pic">
    <img src="https://msu.edu/~donald88/kelsie.jpg" alt="kelsie by river" align="center" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;` - each of these attributes can't get 2 values

Comment: You want the text and the image side by side or below one another?

Comment: `img` elements don't have an `align` attribute. Also you have *unclosed* `<p>` tags while others are closed. Don't mix these two usage types. Both are valid in HTML 5, but I'd recommend to always close any open elements, and b) if you don't want that, that you wouldn't mix it up.

Comment: I'd like them next to each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the **same** **height** on elements in a **row** a good choice would be [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). If the width, for example the text, is getting to small, use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and make the with of the divs 100% and the `flex-direction: column`.

**In total** it could look like:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.whole {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.whole div {
  padding: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.about-text {
  color: #66096c;
  font-family: Lucida bright;
  font-size: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .whole {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .whole div {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .whole img { /* Make image responsive */
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div class="about-text">
    <p> <strong> Hi, I'm Kelsie. </strong> 
      <p>
        <p>Hello there.
          <br />My name is Kelsie, and I like to create things. So I decided to do it for a job. I am learning how to do this at Michigan State University, where I study professional writing. This program teaches web design, print design, editing, and writing.
          I am also learning about how to make rhetorical decisions that will have a positive impact on an audience by studying visual design principles, website accessibility and usability laws, and persuasion techniques.</p>
        <p>I live in East Lansing where I am a full-time student. So basically I study all the time. On the rare occasions that I do have some free time, I like to read, shop, and visit my <span> home</span> cats.</p>
        <p>Want to create something together? Me too. Send me a message using the contact form, and let's get together.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="about_pic">
    <img src="https://msu.edu/~donald88/kelsie.jpg" alt="kelsie by river" align="center" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `margin-left: 0 auto` and `margin-right: 0 auto`.
Simply use `margin: auto` on you main div.

Comment: That didn't change anything, but thank you for the suggestion; I don't know why it won't center with margin: auto !

Comment: Regardless keep that. Then change the two inner divs to have width 50% each. The big one to 80% if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

give `margin-left:30%;` for text as your div width is 50% and remove all right margins from it as if the div is centrally aligned then there is no need to specify margin right

```css
.whole {
  height: 800px;
  max-width: 98%;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.about-text {
  width: 40%;
  color: #66096c;
  font-family: Lucida bright;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left:30%;
}
.about_pic {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="whole">
  <div class="about-text">
    <p> <strong> Hi, I'm Kelsie. </strong> 
      <p>
        <p>Hello there.
          <br />My name is Kelsie, and I like to create things. So I decided to do it for a job. I am learning how to do this at Michigan State University, where I study professional writing. This program teaches web design, print design, editing, and writing.
          I am also learning about how to make rhetorical decisions that will have a positive impact on an audience by studying visual design principles, website accessibility and usability laws, and persuasion techniques.</p>
        <p>I live in East Lansing where I am a full-time student. So basically I study all the time. On the rare occasions that I do have some free time, I like to read, shop, and visit my <span> home</span> cats.</p>
        <p>Want to create something together? Me too. Send me a message using the contact form, and let's get together.</p>
  </div>

  <div class="about_pic">
    <img src="https://msu.edu/~donald88/kelsie.jpg" alt="kelsie by river" align="center" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why should she have her containers float *at all* then?

Comment: how do i know? she wants center aligned. so it might help her

Answer (score -1):

With the traditional box-model, `padding-left` and `padding-right` are *added to an element's `width`*. So your `.about-text` exceeds the `40%` you defined by 1.8em + 6em.

Try to add the following to your CSS to switch the box-model to a more intuitive one:

```
body, html {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* as opposed to the default content-box */
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  /* make that the default box-model for all elements, still allowing simple override if needed */
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

The next issue is with the floating. If an element contains only floated elements, it will collapse to a height of `0`. You need to clear the floats on the parent element to make it contain the floats. You can use the so-called `clearfix`:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

and apply that class to any container that you want to contain floated children.

Comment: Whoever -1'ed, please comment why.

Comment: That code messed a lot of my website up; could I just change the percent width of my .about-text? Or adjust the padding somehow? (I didn't -1, just so you know)

Comment: Nonetheless it is **absolutely essential** that you understand the two different box-models. You have not answered the comment I put underneath your question. As of now, it is unclear what your desired result looks like.

Answer (score -2):

You could always just add a `<center>` and `</center>` directly into your HTML...Or am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: That must be HTML knowledge from 1997. `<center>` has been deprecated for 174 years now. That being said, this is a really *bad recommendation*, and thus, a **really bad answer**.

Comment: Adding `<center>` is a bad recommendation as that tag has been depreciated since HTML4 came out and you should know be using CSS instead. And just because it works does not make it correct.

Comment: No need to overcomplicate things with all that CSS

Comment: It works **only for backwards compatibility reasons**.

Comment: Support for it won't be ending any time soon, and this fixes the problem, therefore this is a perfectly valid answer

Comment: Well its just that `<center>` works perfectly fine and everyone's pondering over the CSS when all you have to do is add 2 simple lines to the HTML file.  There's no reason it should be considered 'bad practice' just because its old.  It works for what it needs to work for, and its served me well countless times over the past 7 years that I've been programming in HTML.  All this CSS is unnecessary.

Comment: and now I'm looking back on this nearly 2 years later, facepalming at my stupidity

Comment: > programming in html, as if html is a scripting language